# How to print out whole numbers alongside fractions in Python using fraction import

Tags: python, math, import, format, fractions

Im trying to print out a whole numbers alongside rational fractions

E.g: 3 1/2    , **not **7/2

I wanted to try to use if statements like
`if num1 >= den1: whole +=`

though i was afraid that wasnt gonna work or mess up everything else i wrote in the code

```py
import fractions

num1 = int(input('Enter 1st number Numerator: '))
den1 = int(input('Enter 1st number Denominator: '))

num2 = int(input('Enter 2nd number Numerator: '))
den2 = int(input('Enter 2nd number Denominator: '))

f1 = fractions.Fraction(num1, den1)
f2 = fractions.Fraction(num2, den2)

equ = str(input('Select Operation, +, * or /?: '))

if equ == '*':
  print('{} * {} = {}'.format(f1, f2, f1 * f2))

if equ == '/':
    print('{} / {} = {}'.format(f1, f2, f1 / f2))

if equ == '+':
    print('{} + {} = {}'.format(f1, f2, f1 + f2))
```

the output is always

1/4 + 5/4 = 3/2

not

1/4 + 5/4 = 1 1/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the output in the format you desire, you can extract the whole number and the fractional part separately and format the output accordingly. Here's a code you can use to do this:

```
import fractions

num1 = int(input('Enter 1st number Numerator: '))
den1 = int(input('Enter 1st number Denominator: '))

num2 = int(input('Enter 2nd number Numerator: '))
den2 = int(input('Enter 2nd number Denominator: '))

f1 = fractions.Fraction(num1, den1)
f2 = fractions.Fraction(num2, den2)

equ = str(input('Select Operation, +, * or /?: '))

if equ == '*':
    result = f1 * f2
elif equ == '/':
    result = f1 / f2
elif equ == '+':
    result = f1 + f2

whole = result.numerator // result.denominator
remainder = result.numerator % result.denominator

if whole != 0 and remainder != 0:
    print('{} {}/{} = {} {}/{}'.format(f1, f2, result.numerator, whole, remainder, result.denominator))
elif whole != 0:
    print('{} {}/{} = {}'.format(f1, f2, result.numerator, whole))
else:
    print('{} {}/{} = {}/{}'.format(f1, f2, result.numerator, remainder, result.denominator))
```

In this code, I've added a section after the computation to extract the whole number and the remainder of the fraction. Then, I check the conditions to format the output correctly. If the whole number and remainder are both non-zero, I print the result in the format of "whole_number remainder/denominator." If only the whole number is non-zero, I print it as "whole_number." Otherwise, I print it as "remainder/denominator."

Now the output should appear as you what you wanted!

Comment: What's the `{} {}/{}` on the left-hand side of the `=` in the `print` statements doing? The output looks quite odd.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tidy little function that would do this for you.

```py
from fractions import Fraction

def convert_improper_fraction_to_mixed_fraction(numerator, denominator):
    # Calculate the whole number
    whole_number = numerator // denominator
    whole_number_str = str(whole_number)
    
    # Calculate the remainder
    remainder = numerator % denominator
    
    # Calculate the proper fraction
    proper_fraction = Fraction(remainder, denominator)
    fraction_str = str(proper_fraction)

    # Return the mixed fraction as string
    return whole_number_str + ' ' + fraction_str
```

And here is a test:

```
num1 = 7
den1 = 4


r = convert_improper_fraction_to_mixed_fraction(num1, den1)

print(r)
```

And the result would look like this:

```
1 3/4
```

You can implement this into your code.

Comment: I would personally make use of the builtin `divmod` to make the code a little cleaner.

Comment: i just improved the function to return a string in the exact way that the question liked...

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal,  nice idea !!  learn something every day....

Comment: Why do the string conversion and concatenation? Just return `f'{whole_number} {proper_fraction}'` :)

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal,  yes, that would be cleaner actually.

Comment: Though a trivially small performance impact in this case, it also reduces the number of constructed strings from 4 to just 1, so it's faster too.